How to do https authentication in Firefox and Safari in Katalon Studio?
I want to access my staging webpage which is protected by username and password. I want to do an https authentication to get in. Currently, I'm able to do this for Chrome and other Chromium based web browsers like Edge. But, in the case of Firefox and Safari this is not working. I'm looking for a method to do this in Katalon.
Currently, in Katalon I'm using
WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://username:password@domains.com/')

to navigate to my webpage which is working for Chrome. But this is not working for Firefox and Safari.
I've also tried
WebUI.authenticate('https://domains.com/', 'username', 'password', 0)

which is also not working.
